# Characteristic polynomial of 4 by 4 function matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

I want to find out the eigenvalues of the following matrix

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    e^{2k+J(p_x+p_y)} & e^{Jp_x} & e^{Jp_y} & e^{-2k-J(p_x+p_y)}\\
    e^{Jp_x} & e^{2k+J(p_x-p_y)} & e^{-2k} & e^{-Jp_y} \\ 
    e^{Jp_y} & e^{-2k}&e^{2k+J(p_y-p_x)} & e^{-Jp_x} \\
    e^{-2k-J(p_y+p_x)} & e^{-Jp_y} & e^{-Jp_x} & e^{2k-J(p_x+p_y)}\\
\end{pmatrix}  
\end{equation}

I can go by brute force. In fact, I calculated the subdeterminants, but the resulting expressing is too lengthy, and the factorization is not obvious at all. Now Shur's decomposition is outside the window because, by default, A and D are non-invertible matrices. Any idea How I could evaluate fast the eigenvalues?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems there won't be a good looking expression.

Comment: @AndrésCárcel I know, but actually I expect it not to be. Is a modified Ising Model, so yep it shouldn't be